# How get control from cell in my DataGridView?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I would like to know if it's possible to directly get control of a specific cell by using its references / column and row indexes.

I noticed that it was possible to get control of a cell from an event.
For example:

From the event "**myDataGridView.CellValidating**" you can obtain the control of the cell being edited as follows

```vb
Dim cellControl As Control = Me.myDataGridView.EditingControl
```

Do you think it's possible to get the same thing without using an event?

Comment: The instance of a cell editing control is created when the edit mode changes (unless it's the same control type as the cached one). You need to subscribe to an event to be notified when the editing control is ready to use. You can subscribe to the [DataGridView.EditingControlShowing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrolshowing) to get the current instance of the edit control type used to edit the content of a cell.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the column and row you wish to access.

```
Private Sub GetCellValue(column As Integer, row As Integer)
    Dim x = DataGridView1(column, row).Value.ToString()
    Debug.Print(x)
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    GetCellValue(1, 3)
End Sub
```